# How to subtract hours from a datetime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, gmt

I get a datetime field, that's currently in the query as:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(x.date_entered, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM x ORDER BY date ASC
```

What I want to do is to subtract 3 hours from that date (GMT issues), but I can't do it in PHP as PHP only knows the date part, not the time.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

mySQL has [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(column, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)....
```

but would it not be better to try and sort out the underlying time zone issue instead?

Comment: Well the GMT isn't exactly a thing I can change (damn legacy) but how to get that in the format I need? `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: @Lucas I'm not sure why you are doing a `DATE_FORMAT()` in the first place - would `DATE(x.date_entered)` not do already? The final line would be `DATE(DATE_SUB(x.date_entered, INTERVAL 3 HOUR))`

Comment: I wanted to pre-format the date in the format I wanted (YYYY/MM/DD), but I wasn't sure of how to do it in PHP, so I did using SQL.

Comment: @Lucas ah, fair enough. Then wrap the DATE_FORMAT around the `DATE_SUB` directive and it should work.

Comment: But how can we subtract the hours so that we can get ( yerterday date and time stamp like 23:00:00 )

Comment: @shzyincu Not sure what you mean? You might want to look into DATE_FORMAT() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have some timezone issue and know source and destination timezone, you could convert it like so

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(x.date_entered, 'UTC', 'Europe/Berlin'),
                   '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
FROM x ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Comment: This is likely a "correct" solution in many cases, but unfortunately it requires the timezone table to have been installed with mysql. Otherwise, you just get NULL. I gave it an up-vote based on those specific timezone issues where it _would_ be the most correct solution. For example, you might have two areas in different time zones, and only one of them uses Daylight Savings, so it will sometimes be 3 hours different, and sometimes 2 hours (or 4).

Answer (score 1):

Normal select query.
[image]

Once applied **DATE_ADD()** function in MySQL

```
select lastname, 
    date_add(changedat, interval -24 hour) as newdate
from employee_audit;
```

**lastname** and **changedat** is field name and **employee_audit** is table name.
[image]