# Trying to figure out how to create this procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I can't seem to figure this out and I've been at it for sometime now any help would be great thank you.

I have to prepare a simple procedure accepting one parameter, a date value, and using date addition functions in SQL (MySql if possible) return the parameter value minus 1 day

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_date
IS 
BEGIN
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)
END;
/
EXEC get_date
```

This was all I could come up with so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

That question is not just about select statement (ie, computing minus one day); I need help with a SQL procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract 3 hours from a datetime using SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020162/how-to-subtract-3-hours-from-a-datetime-using-sql)

Comment: Thank you. I looked at it maybe the answer is staring me in the face. I am not sure. So is the query rite.

Comment: You still need help?

Comment: Yea is the procedure syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just create a [**function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION simplefunction (s datetime)
   RETURNS datetime DETERMINISTIC
   RETURN DATE_SUB(s, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

SELECT simplefunction (anydate);
```

Comment: Thank you i will give that a shot instead.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that i completely forgot. Also it does work that way i appreciate all your help.