# How to Substract time from datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am using a timezone based script where there is deadline based on timezones. Say for example a deadline is on 7th July at 6PM for a person in IST timezone. The deadline should be 1:30 less than 6pm in Dubai as per their timezone.

I have already calculated the difference between the two timezone difference. I am stuck at deducting that calculated time from the deadline time.

I have saved the timezones in +5:40 +4:00 -4:00 this format instead of using php default ones.

Comment: Do you want to get it in query or php ? Where you want to store values? If you want to store in db, show some related table structure and related data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to add and subtract time from a date.
First of all, I get the date from the database and then convert it to a `DateTime` object.

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
```

I use `add` and a `DateInterval` to add time. Here's an example to add hours.

```
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT{$hoursToAdd}H"));
```

And here's and example to subtract hours intead:

```
$date->sub(new DateInterval("PT{$hoursToSubstract}H"));
```

Check this out to know how to work with DateInterval and add/subtract different times: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain a little more specifically what you want to do?

You want to subtract when data already on some var inside your script or you want the SQL query needed ?

If so maybe you can use this answer ---> [How to subtract 3 hours from a datetime in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020162/how-to-subtract-3-hours-from-a-datetime-in-mysql)

The last answer of this post maybe is the one that fit the most what you need :

> Assuming you have some timezone issue and know source and destination timezone, you could convert it like so
>
> ```
> SELECT 
>     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(x.date_entered, 'UTC', 'Europe/Berlin'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
> FROM 
>     x 
> ORDER BY 
>     date ASC;
> ```